# How to remove the author field from bulk/quick edit form?

Tags: quick-edit, bulk-edit

The goal here is to be able to use `add_post_type_support('product','author');` or any other post_type without adding the author field in bulk/quick edit form.

How to remove the author field from bulk/quick edit form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring several options, I landed on this as the cleanest server side alternative:

```
add_filter('admin_head-edit.php',function(){

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if( post_type_supports($screen->post_type,'author' )){
        
        // remove from bulk/quick edit
        
        remove_post_type_support($screen->post_type,'author');

        add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', function($columns){
            
            $columns['author'] = __('Author');
            
            return $columns;
        });
    }
});
```